# Как отключить сообщения о предупреждениях и ошибках ndk-build?

Tags: android-ndk

Как отключить сообщения о предупреждениях и ошибках ndk-build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `$NDK_ROOT/build/core/init.mk` определен вывод сообщений:

```
__ndk_name    := Android NDK
__ndk_info     = $(info $(__ndk_name): $1 $2 $3 $4 $5)
__ndk_warning  = $(warning $(__ndk_name): $1 $2 $3 $4 $5)
__ndk_error    = $(error $(__ndk_name): $1 $2 $3 $4 $5)

ifdef NDK_NO_WARNINGS
__ndk_warning :=
endif
ifdef NDK_NO_ERRORS
__ndk_error :=
endif
```

Определив `NDK_NO_WARNINGS`, `NDK_NO_ERRORS`, можно отключить сообщения о предупреждениях и ошибках скрипта. Но сообщения от самого make останутся.